# Firebase Analytics custom event - unresolved identifier name and text

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to set up Firebase Analytics.
I am trying to log the following custom event inside an @IBAction that is linked to an IB button

```
FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: "go_premium", parameters: [
  "go_premium": name as NSObject,
  "click_on_go_premium_button": text as NSObject
  ])
```

I receive the error messages:
Use of unresolved identifier text and use of unresolved identifier name.
I import Firebase in the view controller. Any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting those errors because you don't have a "name" and a "text" property in the class or function where you are calling this method.

What I think you want to achieve is this:

```
FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: "go_premium", parameters: [
   "name": "Go premium" as NSObject,
   "text": "click_on_go_premium_button" as NSObject
   ])
```

If you can show the rest of your code we can help you further.